# License verification for non-Market distribution channels?

Tags: android, google-play, licensing, android-lvl

Certainly the Google's LVL is the standard for license verification when selling through the official Market, but with the influx of tablets that don't have access to the Market, I'm beginning to look at making my app available through other distribution channels.

How should one attempt license verification when selling through distribution channels other than the Market?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, what I've found is that there really is no present alternative. However, I did receive an e-mail response from AppsLib indicating that they are a few weeks away from releasing their own implementation of LVL for the AppsLib Marketplace. They claim that "when it is released you will only need to add a few lines of code to your apps for it to be compatible with both Google and Appslib."

Answer (score 1):

In that case you need to implement your own DRM mechanism. Trust me its no use using anything other than Android Market for distribution. Not many have it and for paid apps, Marketplace takes a lot of headache off you. I dont think there is any mature Android Distribution Channel other than the Marketplace

Comment: I don't disagree that the Market is the most headache-free way. However, I'm getting a not-insignificant number of requests for my app on tablet devices that do not have the Market, and while I think many people go into alternative markets *hoping* they'll pick up more sales, I actually know that I will be turning my back on potential sales if I don't try to offer another source. I'm hoping that others have forged this same river before and have semi-successful home-brew DRM strategies for solving this problem.

Comment: thats interesting to know. What kind of tablet devices are those from which you are getting requests. I mean the specs for the tablet. It would be nice if u can share that insight there.

Comment: I'm getting requests from owners of Cruz T103 (http://www.cruzreader.com/tablet.php), Archos 70 (http://www.archos.com/products/ta/archos_70it/specs.html?country=us&lang=en) & 101 (http://www.archos.com/products/ta/archos_101it/specs.html?country=us&lang=en), and Galaxy Tab. The Galaxy Tab, of course does have the Market, but it's indicative of people wanting to use it on a tablet, so I'm including it here.

Comment: And actually just now received a request for the Coby Kyros 7005 (http://www.cobyusa.com/?p=prod&prod_num_id=10494&pcat_id=1013).