# Distribution of Android application outside of the Google Play store

Tags: android, google-play, apk

Does anyone know if it's possible to distribute an Android app outside of the Google play store? Say I want to put it on my website for people to download directly. Are there any technical issues with that? Legal issues?

Comment: Legal issues are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Say I want to put it on my website for people to download directly.

Upload APK File on your web server.

> Are there any technical issues with that?

Users will need to check CheckBox on their mobile => Allow Installation of Non-Market Application.

> Legal issues?

As long as you are not using copy-righted/Hacked Libraries

Comment: Would the (free) app update from Play Market if it was installed from another source? It is supposed to be distributed both through the Play Store and other sources (forums, web pages etc.) What about in-app purchases? Would they be available for app installed not from Play Store?

Answer (score 4):

There is absolutely no issue with that.
A click on a link to the apk file will download the file and the user will be able to install it.
MORE: there are alternative markets like the amazon one!

Answer (score 1):

There is the technical question of how you wish to enforce [licensing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937961/license-verification-for-non-market-distribution-channels) (if you need to), which e.g. the Android Market and Amazon Market have already solved.